# ClassCastException: string can't be cast to double

Tags: java, gwt, casting

I have got a Java method (`getTrucks()`), which throws `ClassCastException: string can't be cast to double`.

The method belongs to `FoodTruckServiceImpl`, which implements `FoodTruckService`.

I retrieve the objects via parser, so they are stored with the correct types.

Here is the method:

```
public List<Truck> getTrucks() {

PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
List<Truck>  trucklist = new ArrayList<Truck>();

try {
    Extent e = pm.getExtent(Truck.class, true);
    Iterator iter = e.iterator();
    int count = 0;

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
        Truck t = (Truck) iter.next();
        trucklist.add(t);
    }

    if(count>0){
        System.out.println("get to here(count>0)?!!");
        return trucklist;
    }
} finally {
     pm.close();
}

System.out.println("get to here?!!");
return this.trucklist.getTruckList();
```

}

```
Truck Class:
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Truck {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Persistent
private String key;
@Persistent
private String vendorType;
@Persistent
private String status;
@Persistent
private String businessName;
@Persistent
private String location;
@Persistent
private String description;
@Persistent
private double lat;
@Persistent
private double lon;
@Persistent
private Date createDate;

//constructor for food truck
public Truck() {
    this.createDate = new Date();
}

public Truck(String symbol, String type, String status, String businessName, String location, String description, double lat, double lon) {
    this();
    this.key = symbol;
    this.vendorType = type;
    this.status = status;
    this.businessName = businessName;
    this.location = location;
    this.description = description;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getTruck() {
    return this.key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getVendorType() {
    return this.vendorType;
}

public void setVendorType(String vendorType) {
    this.vendorType = vendorType;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setstatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getBusinessName() {
    return this.businessName;
}

public void setBusinessName(String businessName) {
    this.businessName = businessName;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return this.location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public double getLat() {
    return this.lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public double getLon() {
    return this.lon;
}

public void setLon(double lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

public Date getCreateDate() {
    return this.createDate;
}




}
```

It throws the following error:

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
        com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.client.FoodTruckService.getTrucks()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to      java.lang.Double
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchDoubleField(FetchFieldManager.java:140)
        at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingDoubleField(AbstractStateManager.java:2256)
        at com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.client.Truck.jdoReplaceField(Truck.java)
        at com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.client.Truck.jdoReplaceFields(Truck.java)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1935)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchFields(EntityUtils.java:974)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldValues(JDOStateManager.java:764)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForHollow(JDOStateManager.java:205)
        at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerFactory.newForHollowPopulated(StateManagerFactory.java:89)
        at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactory.newForHollowPopulated(ObjectProviderFactory.java:75)
        at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2882)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1014)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:229)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:226)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:121)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.closingConnection(StreamingQueryResult.java:90)
        at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:108)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.disconnect(StreamingQueryResult.java:78)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOQLQuery$1.managedConnectionPreClose(JDOQLQuery.java:199)
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection.close(DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:147)
        at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.closeAllConnections(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:181)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager$1.preClose(AbstractStoreManager.java:260)
        at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1112)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.internalClose(JDOPersistenceManager.java:359)
            at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.releasePersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:1106)
        at    org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:343)
        at  com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.server.FoodTruckServiceImpl.getTrucks(FoodTruckServiceImpl.java:105)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
            ... 40 more
```

Could anyone please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: I don't see where possibly you're getting an exception in the code snippet you posted. The error is probably in the client side. See the method getTrucks() in the class com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.client.FoodTruckService

Comment: The full getTrucks method I posted is from foodtruckservice class, and in the iterator step, it doesn't correctly run through the whole loop

Comment: The thing is, there's an error log that we're not seeing.  It kinda looks like we're looking at the log on the caller side and not seeing the log on the callee's side.  If you're convinced that the error is on "this" side, add a `catch` block to log the exception stack trace and then rethrow the exception.

Comment: Can you poste de Truck class ?

Comment: posted, I have the Truck class on the client side

Comment: Ah, here we go: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to      java.lang.Double
        at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchDoubleField(FetchFieldManager.java:140)
        at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingDoubleField(AbstractStateManager.java:2256)
        at com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.client.Truck.jdoReplaceField(Truck.java)
        at com.cpsc310.foodtrucker.client.Truck.jdoReplaceFields(Truck.java)`

Comment: nvm I believe it is caused by not correctly storing my double fields (lat, lon) as doubles in the datastore. My importing to datastore method takes in double but somehow when its stored its not actually stored as a double?

Comment: where `this.trucklist.getTruckList();` is defined? How `trunklist` is defined in your serviceImpl class?

Comment: I solved it, stupidest error, my group member had written code that wrote Truck objects to the local datastore as everything strings, so when my getTruck() method ran, it couldn't get some of the Truck objects b/c String cannot be cast to double(expected). I deleted my local database and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

as you method returns `List<Truck>` then simply return `trucklist` NOT `this.trucklist.getTruckList()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is occuring from ToastAndroid so i just removed the line and error went away

```
Platform.OS === "android"
      ? ToastAndroid.show(
          "Congratulations\n",
          "Your profile has been updated",
          ToastAndroid.SHORT
        )
      : Alert.alert("Congratulations", "Your profile has been updated");
```

just implement Toast carefully everything works fine